# Is it possible to decrypt msgstore.db.crypt8 file

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, encryption

I am having a file **msgstore.db.crypt8** that is actually backup file of whatsApp. I don't have a rooted phone so is it still possible to read this file ??

If yes then how can i do that ?

I tried to download some software that extract a key using phone but this process required rooted phone that i don't have.

Answer (score 1):

> **PREREQUISITES:**
>
> 1. O/S: Windows Vista, Windows 7 or Windows 8
> 2. Java - If not installed: [Download Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/)
> 3. ADB (Android Debug Bridge) Drivers - If not installed: [ADB Installer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979)
> 4. USB Debugging* must be enabled on the target device. Settings -> Developer Options -> (Debugging) USB debugging Android device with Android 4.0 or higher
>
> *= If you cannot find Developer Options then please go to: Settings -> About phone/device and tap the Build number multiple times until you're finally declared a developer.
>
> **INSTRUCTIONS:**
>
> 1. Extract "WhatsAppKeyExtract.zip" on your computer maintaining the directory structure.
> 2. Browse to the extracted folder and click on "WhatsAppKeyExtract.bat". Connect your device via USB**, unlock your screen and wait for "Full backup" to appear.
> 3. Leave the password field blank and tap on "Back up my data".
> 4. The "extracted" folder will now contain your "whatsapp.key", "msgstore.db" and "wa.db".
>
> ** = If you have never used USB Debugging before, you may also need to verify the fingerprint.

Source: [[Tool] WhatsApp Key/DB Extractor | OFFICIAL | CRYPT8 | NON-ROOT | UPDATED APRIL 2015](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770982)

Comment: This is an okay answer, but it'd be better if you can also quote the relevant (and important) steps from the XDA forum. If that post is gone, then this answer will be pretty useless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

simple way to read whatsapp crypt8 database messages..

Requirments:-
1. Android mobile 
2. Mobile access of that database which you want to read messages.
3. En or gb whatsapp.

Now you have whole database folder of that mobile you want to read messages.

Install enwhatsapp .
Go to enwhatsapp folder and copy all database files in enwhatsapp database folder.

Now open enwhatsapp and verify that no which is copied in database folder.

Now all messages are restored.

Go to setting< data usage 
And restrict background data pf enwhatsapp.

Now you can read all messages.

To keep messages open in enwhatsapp do to connect your mobile wifi and mobile data to enwhatsapp.

After you verify his no in your mobile .... verify in that mobile also .... so that he cant know that you did this ...

Comment: This seems intriguing, can you edit your post to include a link and screenshot?